# связь между несколькими viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

У меня есть основная ViewModel которая содержит в себе коллекцию Group ViewModels

```
    public class NavigationVM:ViewModelBase
        {

            private ObservableCollection<NavigationGroupViewModel> _groupCollection;        
            public ObservableCollection<NavigationGroupViewModel> GroupCollection
            {
                get { return _groupCollection; }
                set
                {
                    if (_groupCollection != value)
                    {
                        _groupCollection = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("GroupCollection");
                    }
                }
            }
...
...
}
```

в GroupViewModel у меня есть DeleteCurrentCommand который срабатывает при нажатие на ContextMenu item

```
private RelayCommand _deleteCurrentCommand;
        public RelayCommand DeleteCurrentCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_deleteCurrentCommand == null)
                {
                    _deleteCurrentCommand = new RelayCommand((o) =>
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Executed command is  " + "DeleteCurrentCommand");
                    });
                }
                return _deleteCurrentCommand;
            }
        }
```

Теперь мне нужно удалить этот элемент из коллекции GroupCollection которая находится в главном ViewModel NavigationVM. 
Как лучше и правильней это сделать? Можно ли подписаться на DeleteCurrentCommand event из NavigationVM?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы добавил в NavigationVM свойство

```
NavigationGroupViewModel selectedItem;
public NavigationGroupViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                if (value.Equals(selectedItem))
                    return;

            selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

в xaml к элементу, к которому привязана Ваша коллекция добавил бы

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

команду удаления также перенес бы в NavigationVM

```
private RelayCommand _deleteCurrentCommand;
    public RelayCommand DeleteCurrentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deleteCurrentCommand == null)
            {
                _deleteCurrentCommand = new RelayCommand((o) =>
                {
                    SelectedItem.Delete();
                    GroupCollection.Remove(SelectedItem);
                    OnPropertyChanged("GroupCollection");
                });
            }
            return _deleteCurrentCommand;
        }
    }
```

Соответственно, MenuItem в ContextMenu привязал бы к этой команде.

Answer (score 1):

Это по сути не вопрос по MVVM. У вас есть несколько объектов, как им друг с другом связаться?

Ответ — как угодно.

Например, в вашем случае я бы просто передавал ссылку на внешнюю VM в конструктор `NavigationGroupViewModel`, и внутри реализации `DeleteCurrentCommand` тупо вызывал бы публичный метод, передавая себя в качестве аргумента.

Comment: Добрый вечер Влад, "Как угодно" я конечно смогу их связат, но думал может есть способ подписаться на event в mainViewModel. хочется сделать правильно

Comment: @Vadim: Можно и так, конечно. Тут нет предпочтительного способа, делайте как выглядит правильным. Можно и выставить event, если хотите.